# How to store variables in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to save some defined variables in Django (simply said, a model class with only one instance).

For that currently I'm making a model and using `model.object.get( pk=1 )` to get the variable values.

Other option I know about is creating a simple text file and storing variables(as a dict etc.). And reading through that whenever some change is required.

Is there some other easier way of doing that ?

Comment: A model with a single row is not that uncommon, and personally I do not have a huge problem with it. If you however define variables, and these are all of the same type, you might consider a "key"-"value" model, and thus turn it into separate rows.

Comment: But doesn't that make models.py look unprofessional ?

Comment: I do not really see why creating a model is that "hard"?

Comment: It's not hard, but I was assuming there might be some other straightforward way which I may not know.

Comment: Well this is in its core the *Singleton pattern* (https://steelkiwi.com/blog/practical-application-singleton-design-pattern/). There is however some debate whether a singleton is a pattern, or an anti-pattern. The fact that one uses a model, however can easily later turn it into a non-singleton.

Comment: Thanks for giving insights :D

Comment: well an alternative is for example a JSON dictionary, or anything like that. A problem with this is that you each time load the *entire* file, whereas you might be interested in only a subpart. If after a while the number of items become large, this can result in a bottleneck.

Comment: Yes!, this sounds like synonymous to text file option I mentioned in question.

Comment: What is the semantics of that "variable"? How is it utilized in your app?

Comment: The key here is: are your variable values modified and saved dynamically by users, or are they more like settings that are modified only by the programmer?  If they are more like settings, then it is simpler to define a dictionary and include it in your settings file.

Comment: @powderflask They're are continuously getting updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to just store a single, static value, then just keeping it in your `settings.py` is sufficient as others have mentioned.

But if you require that users are able to edit it, may I suggest [`django-aboutconfig`](https://pypi.org/project/django-aboutconfig/)? *Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of that plugin*

Comment: This is great, but can you please elaborate a bit about the config model instance. I'm unable to figure out that.

Comment: I'd love to help but not sure where you're lost. Here's a quick guide - https://imgur.com/a/w85F6yT

Comment: Thanks! this helped.

Comment: Feel free to tell me if there's anything missing/wrong, I'm open to suggestions from real users

Answer (score 1):

django-constance is a really good option.

> Easily migrate your static settings to dynamic settings.
> Admin interface to edit the dynamic settings.

https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance